# Fill table using others tables in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I got three table with Table A linked to Table B and Table B linked to Table C

Table A :

```
id     code          name
1      GFLA2021L     AC2020
2      GFLB2021A     PM2015
...
```

Table B :

```
id    code_A       code  
1     GFLA2021L    GFLA2021L1 
2     GFLA2021L    GFLA2021L2
3     GFLB2021A    GFLB2021A1
```

Table C :

```
id    code_B       number
1     GFLA2021L1   12
2     GFLA2021L2   41
3     GFLA2021A1   9
```

And I want a new table fill with that data for example :

Table expected :

```
id  name     number
1   AC2020   53     <---- 12 + 41
2   PM2015   9
```

But, I don't know how to do it in Django ...

If someone can explain me how to create that table auto fill with data from these 3 tables for having what I except.

Answer (score 0):

```
Logically you can call save function for model D (to fill automatically) when you save data from model C.
for example:
in model C overwrite the def method:
def save(self):
   ## provide data and save to the tabel from here
   super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```